# Unable to update Document folder at runtime

Tags: ios, swift

Running into saving issues with Document folder at run time. The document folder only save the new data for the session and reversed back to the old version after app restarted. This doesn't happen on the simulator only with a signed ipa. Is it a permission issues?

```
static public func updateJson() -> Bool{
    do{
        //try FileManager.default.replaceItemAt(Constants.getJSONPath(), withItemAt: Constants.getDataSyncJsonPath())
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: Constants.getJSONPath())
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: Constants.getDataSyncJsonPath(), to: Constants.getJSONPath())
        print("Updating Json")
        return true
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Your are not providing enough information for anyone to help you solve this problem.

Comment: What error are you receiving, what is the path and path setup you're using?